# How can I play a youtube video AND ncmpcpp at the same time?

Tags: pulseaudio, youtube, ncmpcpp

When I play music in ncmpcpp, youtube videos do not work (vice versa)

I can only play one at a time, why is that? How do I fix it?

on macOS I could play ncmpcpp and youtube videos at the same time, and now I'm curious as to why.

(**update a week later:** For anyone who finds this in the future, I decided to use cmus + cava as a workaround, since cmus works with everything else.)

**update three weeks later:** cmus + vis works fine, you just gotta compile cli-visualizer with pulse. https://github.com/dpayne/cli-visualizer#pulse-audio-setup-easy

**update a month later:** I found the solution, it's this answer right here: https://askubuntu.com/a/555484/913725

Comment: Please don't put solved in the title and the answer in the question. The "Your Answer" window is for the solution to the problem. Please answer your own question and accept it as correct. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you must load a module with pulse audio control:

```
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

after
putting

```
audio_output {
   type     "pulse"
   name     "My PULSE Device"
   server   "127.0.0.1"
```

in `/etc/mpd.conf`

You can `pactl unload-module module-native-protocol-tcp` to unload the module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your audio output, Just go to your mpd.conf and comment out the `pulse audio` part and comment in `Alsa` audio output. Then restart mpd, it should work!